# Concatenating arrays in a Alpine.data objects returns proxies

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I'm working with a `Alpine.data` global and I'm looking to concatenate arrays when my `loadJobs` method fires. I'm not familiar to proxies in JS and I don't really understand why my `data` property returns a Proxy object instead of a simple array.

Here's the piece of code I'm working with :

```js
jobState = {
    low: 5,
    high: 10,
    isLoaded: false
}

document.addEventListener("alpine:init", () => {
    Alpine.data("loadMoreJobs", () => ({
        data: [],
        loadJobs() {
            // Update jobState
            jobState.low = jobState.high
            jobState.high += 5
            const requestParams = {
                dataType: 'json',
                method: 'GET'
            }
            fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:3000/jobs/list/${jobState.low}/${jobState.high}`, requestParams)
                .then((data) => {
                    return data.json()
                })
                .then((data) => {
                    this.data = [...this.data, data]
                })
        }
    }))
})
```

Comment: Don't suppose you ever got to the bottom of this?  I'm struggling with it myself at the moment!!

Comment: I found a way around with some kind of quite dirty trick, but it's working :

```// I have the data variable containing JSON back from the API call

this.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data));
data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
this.data = this.data.concat(data);
```

Comment: I originally asked because it looked like your problem was linked to mine. After more investigation I don't think it is. The fact that the data (your array) is wrapped in a `Proxy()` doesn't matter in the slightest -- you can still treat it as an array. If you can't, there's probably a more fundamental problem in the code (made worse by the fact that you're using the name `data` both as an argument and a class variable!!).  I also found on my travels that the `parse(stringify(data))` solution is just a way to paper over the cracks. Most likely there is a more fundamental error in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I read that it was not supposed to matter indeed. I changed the variable names to make it clear in the example, but they're not called this way in my code, so I guess there is another error somewhere as you're pointing. Maybe you should add your comment as an answer to my question so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 1):

`data` logs out as `Proxy` because that's how Alpine.js' reactivity works: it wraps all relevant objects in Proxy in order to hook into changes into said objects.

The Proxies should work the same as the underlying data structures, the only difference is Alpine can hook into operations on the proxy (re-assignment, mutation etc.).

As mentioned in the comments thread. One way to unwrap the Proxy and get a copy of the original data structure is to use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` (or another deep-cloning approach eg. [`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) which isn't [widely available yet](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_structuredclone)).